# how we can access printer of computer from remote host if we know the ip and port number computer

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

i'm trying to develop an java application to access my PC's printer via a remote host. so that i can submit print job there and take print.i'm trying use UDP as my communication protocol. is there anyway to do this.

Comment: Apart from being off-topic (check the FAQ), UDP is the wrong communication protocol for that.

Comment: Wrong???? can you be more specific...!